# why is GAE not finding the files in my templates folder?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, jinja2

I'm so confused. The thing worked fine last night and all of a sudden today stopped working.

The purpose of this page is to generate a list of colors. The templates are located in their own folder called "templates", but GAE can't seem to find these templates at all.

What am I doing wrong here?

main2.py:

```
import bottle
from bottle import static_file
from google.appengine.ext.webapp import util
from bottle import route

# Load the template system
from jinja2 import Environment, FileSystemLoader

# Indicate from where the templates will be loaded
env = Environment(loader=FileSystemLoader('./templates/'))

# for randomly picking colors
import random

colors = 'green red blue';

@route('/favicon.ico')
def send_image():
    filename = 'favicon.ico'
    return static_file(filename, root='./images/', mimetype='image/ico');

@route('/hello')
def hello():
    template = env.get_template('home.html');
    color_list = colors.split();
    num_colors = random.randint(0,len(color_list)+1);
    color_list = color_list[:num_colors];
    return template.render(title="Color List Page!", color_list=color_list);

util.run_wsgi_app(bottle.default_app())
```

app.yaml

```
application: yao-webapp2
version: 1
api_version: 1
runtime: python

handlers:
- url: .*
  script: main2.py
```

/templates/base.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>
        {% block title %}
        I am stupid as heck: I forgot to fill in a title.
        {% endblock %}
    </title>
    </head>
    <body>
        {% block content %}
        No body knows the trouble I've seen.
        {% endblock %}
    </body>
</html>
```

/templates/home.html

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block title %}
    {{page_title}}
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
    <h1>Some Colors I know </h1>
    <p>I have a list of colors that I know</p>
    {% if color_list %}
        <ul>
        {% for color in color_list %}
            <li> {{ color }} </li>
        {% endfor %}
        </ul>
    {% else %}
        <p>Oops! No colors.</p>
    {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

not sure what error you are getting but i would try to use absolute paths.

instead of

```
env = Environment(loader=FileSystemLoader('./templates/'))
```

try to use this code:

```
templatespath = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "templates")
env = Environment(loader=FileSystemLoader(templatespath))
```

Comment: well the only error GAE tells me is that its 404 =/, should i replace __file__ with something else or just leave it as is? i tried it and it still gives me an 404

Comment: its giving you a 404 on /hello ?

Comment: yes, when i just go to ":8080" it shows "hello world", then when i tried "localhost:8080/hello" it gives me the 404...

Comment: but you are not mapping anything to '/' in your main2.py so i assume you have a main.py. it this your complete yaml?

Comment: and it does not on your local dev server?